# OnClick event not working in dropdown option

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I have dropdown, When I choose option it will retrieve value from database and will shown on text feild. So I did Click function. Its worked in **Firefox** But not worked in **Google Chrome.**

HTML:

```
   <select id="classi" name="classi">
    <option value="1" onclick="chagePack('<?php echo sha1('month11')?>',1,10);">1 months</option>
    <option value="2" onclick="chagePack('<?php echo sha1('month23')?>',3,20);">3 months</option>
    <option value="3" onclick="chagePack('<?php echo sha1('month36')?>',6,30);">6 months</option>
   </select>
```

Javascript:

```
function chagePack(pack,month,type)
{
 alert("test");
 $.post("change_membership_page",
 {
    pack: pack, month: month, type:type
 },
 function(data, status){
     $("[id='replace-month-pack']").html(data); 
    //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
 }); 
}
```

Comment: Use onchange on select

Comment: you can use onchange event

Comment: Onchange also not worked

Comment: check answer given by @Moksh shah

Comment: Check my answer, you missed single quotation `'` mark.

Comment: no thats not problem. I missed that comma here only.The main problem is its not worked in google chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is considered a bad practice to listen for click event on the `select` element. You make it impossible to use the keyboard.

Instead use the `change` event, which works everywhere. You may change your functionality a bit, but you still have access to the data each `option` has.

HTML:

```
<select id="classi" name="classi">
    <option value="1" data-params="1,1,10">1 months</option>
    <option value="2" data-params="2,3,20">1 months</option>
    <option value="3" data-params="3,6,30">1 months</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#classi").on('change', function(){
    var params = $(this).children(':selected').data('params');
    alert(params);
});
```

Online: http://jsfiddle.net/haytzsr8/

Comment: Thank you so much @skip405 I got result

Answer (score 1):

You missed one single quotation `'` mark.

Instead of this

```
  <option value="1" onclick="chagePack('1,1,10);">1 months</option>
```

Use this

```
<option value="1" onclick="chagePack('1,1,10');">1 months</option>
```

Your overall code should look like this

```js
function chagePack(pack,month,type)
{
 alert("test");
 $.post("change_membership_page",
 {
    pack: pack, month: month, type:type
 },
 function(data, status){
     $("[id='replace-month-pack']").html(data); 
    //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
 }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="classi" name="classi">
    <option value="1" onclick="chagePack('1,1,10');">1 months</option>
    <option value="2" onclick="chagePack('2,3,20');">1 months</option>
    <option value="3" onclick="chagePack('3,6,30');">1 months</option>
</select>
```

Comment: here only i missed comma.

Comment: my actual code is  <option value="1" onclick="chagePack('<?php echo sha1("month11")',1,10);">1 months</option>

Comment: your php code should be: `<option value="1" onclick="chagePack('<?php echo sha1("month11"); ?>',1,10)">1 months</option>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `onChange` event instead of `onClick`.

`OnClick` is not standard event for `SELECT` tag.

Comment: are you getting any error in console? did u checked ajax in Network tab? how did you came to know that this is not working?

Comment: Thanks @apul.  I got result

Answer (score 1):

```
      Worked 
       <select id="classical" name="classical" >
         <option value="1" data-params="<?php echo sha1('month11')?>,1,1">1 months</option>
         <option value="2" data-params="<?php echo sha1('month31')?>,3,2">3 months</option>
         <option value="3" data-params="<?php echo sha1('month61')?>,6,3">6 months</option>
      </select>



     $("#classical").on('change', function(){
        var params = $(this).children(':selected').data('params');
        var val = params.split(',');
        chagePack(val[0],val[1],val[2]);
     }); 

   function chagePack(pack,month,type)
   {
       $.post("change_membership_page",
       {
          pack: pack, month: month, type:type
       },
       function(data, status){
          $("[id='replace-month-pack']").html(data); 
       });  
    }
```